# DataGridView and DataTable: program freeze

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

There is a very strange situation: my application has different behavior while running in VS dubugger and directly as EXE.

After gathering some data, I put the resulting `DataTable` into `DataGridView` with this code:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = null;
dataGridView.DataSource = x.Table; //x.Table is DataTable
```

There is another question: why doesn't `DataGridView` refresh without setting it's `DataSource` to `null`, and I'd be very glad to know the answer, but it's not so important right here.

So, the most important: when I run my application in VS debugger, this code block works properly, but when I run the EXE, execution breaks on the second of lines (I see it in the log written), program freezes and doesn't respond.

I've also found out, that replacing the second code line by

```
dataGridView.DataSource = x.Table.Copy();
```

makes it work in both cases.
Does anybody have an idea on the situation reasons?

Comment: dataGridView.DataSource = x.Table;
dataGridView.DataBind();

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't mention, that I'm using not WPF, but WinForms which have no `DataGridView.DataBind` method